# open new browser with print preview

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a button, which gives a print preview option of the page it is viewing.

This works however instead of loading the print preview in the same browser I would like a new browser to be opened and display the preview when the button is clicked.

```
<a href='@Url.Action("Index", "Print", new { id = Model.DeliveryRunID })'>
            <button>Print Preview</button>
       </a>
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add the `target="_blank"` attribute to your anchor:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Print", new { id = Model.DeliveryRunID })" target="_blank">
    <button>Print Preview</button>
</a>
```

Remark: `<button>` is an invalid element to be nested in an anchor. You've got invalid HTML!

The correct approach here is to use a normal anchor and CSS to make it look like a button:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    "Print Preview", 
    "Index", 
    "Print", 
    new { id = Model.DeliveryRunID }, 
    new { target = "_blank", @class = "button" }
)
```

and of course your CSS rule:

```
.button {
    ...
}
```